# Manage namespaces of multi HTML fragments

Tags: php, dom, architecture, xhtml, xml-namespaces

Excuse my english first... :)

I use `XMLNS` for `HTML` tags and target them in `JS` with `getElementsByTagNameNS` and use the `CSS` selector `xmlns\:tagName` for `CSS` documents, in the server side i use `DOM` with the `PHP` object `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagNameNS`...

I want to know if i did well or if there is a efficient way? this logic could causes me a problem in the future? i dont know how ex: `DRUPAL` or `JOOMLA` manage the thing?

Or you thinking that may be i should use regexp in PHP with `preg_match_replace` to add prefixes in any HTML attributes, and do the same in JS files and CSS files?

structure

```
                        actor
                          |
                          |
                          v
                   +--------------+         +--------------------------------+
                   |  NPresenter  |         |  NNamespace                    |
          +-------+|--------------|+------->|--------------------------------|
          |        |--------------|         |--------------------------------|
          |        | -display();  |         | +full_qualified_js_name();     |
          |        +--------------+         | +full_qualified_less_name();   |
          |                                 | +full_qualified_layout_name(); |
          |                                 +--------------------------------+
          v
 +------------------+                          (assets)
 |  NModel          |                          +------------+
 |------------------|                          | js         |
 |------------------|------------------------->| less       |
 | +file_content(); |                          | layout     |
 +----------------- +                          +------------+
```

fully_qualified_*_name() return a output of target file, with regexp and preg_match_all, i add XMLNS in layout file like below :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <html xmlns:aa='zz' xmlns:ee='rr'>
    <head>
       <title></title>
       <script src="/assets/js/appended_js.js"></script>
       <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/js/appended_css.css"">
    </head>
    <body>
        <aa:span id="span1">
           <aa:p>aaa</aa:p>
        </aa:span>
        <ee:span id="span1">
           <ee:p>aaa</ee:p>
        </ee:span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

in less file i do like below :

```
/*less*/
aa\:span{background: #00ff00;}
```

in js file i do like below :

```
/*js*/
var Namespace = {
    methode1: function() {
       var target = document.getElementsByTagNameNS("aa","zz");

       return target.length;
    }
};
```

Comment: You probably should add an example demo-code so that it's clear what you actually do. I'm not sure if there aren't some little mistakes you ask about, so show some examples that this becomes more clear.

Comment: @hakre thanks for reaction, i'v just post more details, if it steel not clear please ask...

Comment: +1 for the edit alone, this now is much more clear.

Comment: So the only thing that doesn't look straight forward to me is that you're using preg_replace to insert the namespaces. Why don't you for example do that with DOM?

Comment: ahh ok I i didn't know that DOM has a namespace methode, you mean DOMDocument::createElementNS, i'v just see it in [link]http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelementns.php), thanks I'll test it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Javacript side you can use the [jQuery Xmlns plugin](https://github.com/rfk/jquery-xmlns). It allows you to use namespace aware css selectors.

```
var feedTitle = $().xmlns(
  {
    atom : 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
  },
  function () {
    return this.find("atom|channel > atom|title");
  }
).text();
$('#feedTitle').text(feedTitle);
```

In PHP you can use Xpath to query your DOM.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($file);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

$feedTitle = $xpath->evaluate('string(//atom:channel/atom:title)', NULL, FALSE));
```

To create elements inside a namespace use DOMDocument::createElementNS().

Three important points:

1. If you define your own namespaces, the result is not HTML any more. The browser will not recognize/render the elements.
2. Do not confuse the namespace prefix with the actual namespace. The namespace is the string in the xmlns:* attribute. It should be a globally unique string. (That's why urls are used here often.) The namespace prefix is a short alias for the namespace string but only valid vor the current branch of the current document until redefined.
3. You always define own prefix to namespace mapping for querys (css selectors or xpath). This way your queries are unambiguous.